# How to select all div in `.content` but not contain the div I don't want to?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to select all div in `.content` but not contain the div I don't want to?

```
.content div:not(class="a", class="c"){ // not work
    display: none;
}

<div class="content"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain them together, and use `.a` or `.c` for classes `a` and `c`:

```css
.content div:not(.a):not(.c){
    display: none;
}
```

[**Working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xta7Z/)